# Binding not worked for Height and Width properties of ItemsControl in WinRT(metro apps)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I have Binded the Height and Width property with its parent, while resize the metro app(through snapping), the binding is not working.

```
<Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyControl">
                <Grid   >
                    <local:MyPanel Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" >
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MainContent}"/>
                        <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SubContents}"   
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel >
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <local: MyPanel Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </local:MyPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Tried TemplateBinding, TemplatedParent, ElementNameBinding with the Height and ActualHeight Properties, but no luck.

Comment: can u add the code ?? use ActualWidth and ActualHeight for binding

Comment: Hi Heena, ActualHeight and ActualWidth also not working, modified the question, pls find the above code snippet.

Comment: This assumes the MyControl instance has the correct width/height, either explicitly (if you use Width/Height) or effectively (if you use ActualWidth/Height). Is the size correct if you just look at the outer grid in your control template?

Comment: I guess so, so that the child items also get the Size while resize(snapping the metro app) the control. @Nicholas W